# has_many when primary_key's are available without a definite model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

There is a model named: Author which has many books.

For legacy reasons, there is a column in the `authors` table, named: favorite_books which is basically an array of the ids of the favorite books by an author.

I'd like to define a `has_many` association in the `Author` model to books based on those ids in the `favorite_books` column. Something like the following:

```
  class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :books, through: -> { favorite_books } # it's invalid code as of now
  end
```

Through the documentation, there are options like `source` & `source_type` that we can pass, but I'm not sure if it's possible to pass a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't build an association like that. You have two options

Define a method like this which will return a collection

```
def favorite_books
  Booke.where(id: self.favorite_books)
end
```

This is not a full fledged association, so you won't have nice things like `author.favourite_books << Book.new` and so on.

Alternative approach, but requiring more work, is to refactor this into many to many relationship between Author and Book. There are two way to go about it in Rails, either `has_many through` or has_and_belongs_to_many`. Rails Guides has an excellent section on how to choose one over the other https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Second solution would require a data migration which would possibly be a multi step process:

- create a new table
- populate the data in a new table based on the existing column
- drop the column
  There are considerations on how to do it to avoid downtime, data loss, etc.

Happy to expand the answer if you have any follow up questions.

Comment: The problem with defining a method is: it returns an object with the class: `ActiveRecord_Relation`. While an association(`has_many`) returns an object of the class: `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`.

Defining an association via a method, later on, affects the JSON response too.

Comment: As you said, it's legacy code, there's no perfect solution. I'm not sure how does the difference between AR_R and AR_A_CP reflect in JSON?